# ASP.NET Web Pages (with Razor syntax) Life Cycle

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-2

I could only find [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178472.aspx) but at some point it talks about the IsPostback property so I think it might be for the ASP.NET Web Forms.

Is there any information relative to the ASP.NET Web Pages Life Cycle?

Update: When I use some JavaScript, how it is related with the Life Cycle of an IController instance?

Comment: What framework are you asking about ASP.NET Web Pages, ASP.NET Web Forms or ASP.NET MVC?

Comment: Hi Stilgar, thanks. ASP.NET MVC

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe you mean the life cycle of the controller. If so you should also find this useful

[The Life And Times of an ASP.NET MVC Controller](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dd695917.aspx)

Comment: Hi Iridio, thank you for you answer. I am aware of this because I use a DI Container were I explicitly register their lifetime as well. I updated my question.

Comment: this post http://haacked.com/archive/2011/08/18/calling-asp-net-mvc-action-methods-from-javascript.aspx could give you some other insight

Answer (score 1):

JavaScript code is always executed when th page is served to the client. This is true regardless of the technology you use. All serverside code is already executed when the page is served to the client therefore JavaScript executes after it.

Answer (score -1):

ASP.NET Web Page is a view engine (with razor syntax), just like other view engines, It only do render your data + template to html.
It is usually used with ASP.NET MVC. If you want to know how request and response work in ASP.NET MVC, you can read these articles [ASP.NET MVC Architecture](http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/understanding-models-views-and-controllers-cs), [Routing](http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/asp-net-mvc-routing-overview-cs) and [Filtering](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg416513%28VS.98%29.aspx)

Comment: ASP.NET Web Pages is a separate framework for web development like ASP.NET MVC and ASP.NET Web Forms.

Comment: Thank Stilgar for clarifying me. I am actually confused with them.